# GTK rendering using cairo gles

Tags: opengl-es, gtk, cairo, egl

I have successfully changed the backend of cairo that GTK uses to GLES(in the X11 window implementation). I am using a eglWIndowSurface for every gdkwindow. The problem I am facing is that because GTK is doing differential rendering I get to see only the current focus region rendered. Is there any way we can make GTK to render complete window all the time?

Comment: How did you make GTK use GLES? (And why?) Also, shouldn't differential rendering be enough? Where/how is the eglWindowSurface cleared? What's an eglWindowSurface anyway, is this something coming from GTK?

Comment: I want to use the hardware acceleration for gtk. By eglWindowSurface, I mean the window surface that we create with the eglCreateWindowSurface Api. Such a window surface have two buffers attached to it and all GTK rendering happens in a back buffer. At the time of cairo_gl_surface_swapbuffers, backbuffer and front buffesr are flipped (not copied in our implementation).The behavior will be fine if GTK renders the whole window to backbuffer each time. But because GTK invalidates only focused region, the back buffer(i.e the flipped front) will have only the damaged region +rest of area cleared.

Comment: the EGL extension EGL_EXT_swap_buffers_with_damage supports this. But unfortunately our hardware doesnot support this.